# Extract Values from DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I'm working on an edit admin form and I'm populating two DropDownLists (hours and mins) from a DB. I need to extract the hours ([12 hour format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_notation)) and minutes from the returned DateTime object in the DB. Here's what I've tried:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(biz.GetStartDateByID(classID).ToString());
int hrs = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.ToString()).Hour;
```

For "2012-03-08 22:45:00.000" in the DB, this gives "22" for hours. What's the best way of extracting the hours in 12 hour format and the minutes? For example, if the hours value in the DateTime object was "18", I'd need it as "6".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int hrs24 = dt.Hour;
int hrs12 = hrs24 > 12 ? hrs24 - 12 : (hrs24 == 0 ? 12 : hrs24);
```

Comment: Thanks John, I think I need to take a break!

Comment: The property is `Hour`, not `Hours`.

Comment: @JohnPick: Good catch. I fixed the midnight problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String.Format("{0:hh}", dt);
```

This will give you the hour in 12-hour, zero-padded format.

For no zero-padding:

```
String.Format("{0:h}", dt);
```

Comment: DateTime.ToString() has an overload that supports formatting directly: DateTime.Now.ToString("{hh}").

Comment: @DPeden, you don't need the curly braces when you pass a format specifier to ToString; in fact I suspect that including them will trigger an exception.

Comment: @phoog I suppose they are optional.  I ran that code in a unit test before posting it.  ;)

Comment: @DPeden `DateTime.Now.ToString("{hh}")` returns `"{10}"` -- did you assert the return value in your unit test?

Comment: @phoog You are correct, it does return "{10}".  So no, the braces are not appropriate here (and were unintentionally left in when pasting from torrential's format string above).  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.Hour % 12
```

That will give 0-11 of course... do you want 1-12? If so:

```
((DateTime.Hour + 11) % 12) + 1
```

I don't think there's anything simpler built in...

you can visit this link also...
http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm

Answer (score 0):

Just use the proper format for DateTime to string conversion

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(biz.GetStartDateByID(classID).ToString());
int hrs = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.ToString("hh:mm:ss")).Hour;
```

For reference please look at [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-format)

Comment: I tried using the "h" specifier but got null exception - in the article, it says this has changed.

Comment: I just have updated my answer. "hh:mm:ss" is giving me the right value.

Comment: If you read the question, you will see that I am only interested in hours (12 hour format) and minutes; nothing else...